# How to open a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I'm trying to use Hyper-V in a Windows Enterprise Edition machine. 
After installing it I realized that the menu do not show up any way to create a virtual machine. Luckily Hyper-V has a command `Hyper-V Quick Create` which I searched in the Cortana menu, but now I am stuck in the process of opening the virtual machine after having shut it down.

How do I do this? The manager shows no buttons nor menus.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well seems my problem was way easier than expected... I forgot to execute hyper-v as administrator. 
Problem solved.
Very sorry for asking this!

Comment: No need to be sorry. Normally, most built-in MMC configurations automatically (silently) run as Administrator. However, they can also run as a regular user. You may have some settings that disable automatic elevation (maybe set by your IT department).